# Crash tapping on UILabel - using UIApplication shared keyWindow rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, hybrid-mobile-app

I am fairly new to Swift, I am writing a plugin for a hybrid App (Cordova).

I managed to have the App rootController display a ViewController with a game inside and a separate UIView header at the top that contains a UILabel as a back button.

I am experiencing a crash as soon as I tap on the back button.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import SomeFramework;

@objc (MyIntegration) class MyIntegration : SomeFrameworkDelegate {
    func implementedFunctionForDelegate(_ controller: FwViewController) {
      print("fwViewControllerDidHandleSomeEvent");
    }
    // ...

    @objc(launchGame:)
    func launchGame() {
      // Prep params
      let params = FwLaunchParameters.init()
      params.gameId = gameId
      
      // ViewController init
      let gameController = FwViewController.init(gameLaunchParameters: params)
      gameController.delegate = self
      
      // Display game using rootViewController
      let currentWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
      currentWindow?.rootViewController?.present(gameController, animated: true, completion: nil)

      let backHomeHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 80.0))
      let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 28, width: 200, height: 50))
      label.text = "\u{3008} Back Home"
      label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: currentWindow?.rootViewController, action: Selector("handleTap"))
      label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
      
      handleTap() // prints out the log as expected

      // Display header
      currentWindow?.addSubview(backHomeHeader)
      backHomeHeader.addSubview(label)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
      print("tapped! yay!")
    }
}
```

Error log right before the crash:

```
2021-07-31 01:17:24.790750-0400 MyApp[53004:2197131] -[MainViewController handleTap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb44906490
2021-07-31 01:17:24.842133-0400 MyApp[53004:2197131] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController handleTap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb44906490'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422fba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20193ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
```

Note: I use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` because it's a hybrid App (Cordova) and I'm writing a plugin that allows some Javascript code to launch an html5 game using Apple On-Demand Resources.

Everything works fine except for the Back Home button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Target` is an object to which `action` should be sent. You need to move `handleTap` to your `FwViewController` or to replace target with `self`, like this:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
```

Also always prefer `#selector` to `Selector` because it'll give you an error if you're using a wrong selector.

Comment: I cannot alter the FwViewController being a third party fw. Using self and #selector worked, thanks! <3

Comment: Actually, the crash is resolved but it still does not print out the log. It does only when I comment out `currentWindow?.rootViewController?.present(gameController, ..`. As soon as I bring that back, taps on the back button do not print out the log anymore.. :(

Comment: Solved adding the subview to `gameController` rather than `currentWindow`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The crash says that the `MainViewController` has no method with the name `handleTap`

It seems `currentWindow?.rootViewController` is `MainViewController`  and the `handleTap` function is in `MyIntegration` class.

So pass in `self` as the target or implement the `handleTap` inside the `MainViewController` for this case.

Comment: Actually, the crash is resolved but it still does not print out the log. It does only when I comment out `currentWindow?.rootViewController?.present(gameController, ..`. As soon as I bring that back, taps on the back button do not print out the log anymore.. :(

Comment: No, no crash now. But the log is never printed. It gets printed only if I do not present the gameController..

Comment: Solved adding the subview to `gameController` rather than `currentWindow`. Thanks